# Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=200 "Updated Record Does Not Exist"

Tags: ios, contacts

When I run the following code, I get this error at the last try statement:

> Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=200 "Updated Record Does Not Exist"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The save request failed because it
>   updates a record that does not exist or has already been deleted.,
>   CNInvalidRecords=(
>       "" ), NSLocalizedDescription=Updated Record Does Not
>   Exist}

I don't understand the error.  As you see the record for the CNGroup clearly exists, because I just created it without errors.  I also checked in the simulator.  The contact and group both exist.

```
    let store = CNContactStore()

    let defaultContainerIdentifier = store.defaultContainerIdentifier()

    let cnMutableGroup = CNMutableGroup()

    cnMutableGroup.name = "Temple5"

    let groupIdentifier = cnMutableGroup.identifier

    let cnMutableContact = CNMutableContact()

    cnMutableContact.familyName = "Ralph5"

    cnMutableContact.givenName = "Rolfson5"

    let contactIdentifier = cnMutableContact.identifier

    let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()

    saveRequest.add(cnMutableGroup, toContainerWithIdentifier: defaultContainerIdentifier)

    saveRequest.add(cnMutableContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: defaultContainerIdentifier)

    do {

        try store.execute(saveRequest)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error)

    }

    let predicateGroups = CNGroup.predicateForGroups(withIdentifiers: [groupIdentifier])

    var cnGroups: [CNGroup] = []

    do {

        cnGroups = try store.groups(matching: predicateGroups)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error)

    }

    let cnGroup = cnGroups.first!

    let predicateContacts = CNContact.predicateForContacts(withIdentifiers: [contactIdentifier])

    let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

    var cnContacts: [CNContact] = []

    do {

        cnContacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicateContacts, keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error)

    }

    let cnContact = cnContacts.first!

    saveRequest.addMember(cnContact, to: cnGroup)

    do {

        try store.execute(saveRequest)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error)

    }
```

Comment: Hi, @ShinehahGnolaum, I have same problem, did you figure it out?

Comment: @Jerome No I haven't.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing nil for your container identifier.

```
saveRequest.add(cnMutableContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
```

Comment: Using nil will make iOS add the contact to the default container, but you need to add it to the container that the group resides in (which may not be your default) so this won't always work.